# Selenium Python - unable to select by Xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm having an issue clicking an `icon/link` in a table. I've tried both `find_element_by_xpath` and `find_elements_by_Xpath` - no luck with either. I forced the wait as I was getting some issues with the element not being found.

I've highlighted the icon in the Table row, with the red box.  in this image.
[Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qmw41.png)

Also found the Xpath but can't seem to get it to work, the icon is clickable on the webpage.
[Xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olPEm.png)

My **code** is below:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(7)
tr = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="AthleteTheme_wt6_block_wtMainContent_wt9_wtClassTable_ctl05_AthleteTheme_wt221_block_wtIconSvg_Svg"]/svg/use')

tr.click()
```

Thanks

Comment: try `print(tr.page_source)` and check whether the code in this output is same as that appears in your browser's inspect of that website

Comment: What website is it on? also xpath for svgs go /*[name()='svg'] and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

The Element is in an `svg` tag. And there is a different syntax for the same. Links to refer - [Link1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-use-xpath-in-selenium-webdriver-to-grab-svg-elements), [Link2](https://www.inviul.com/svg-elements-xpath-selenium/)

To access `svg` tag elements the syntax would something like this:

```
//*[local-name()='svg']
```

As per the screen shot the xpath for the Elements would be:

```
//span[@id="AthleteTheme_wt6_block_wtMainContent_wt9_wtClassTable_ctl05_AthleteTheme_wt221_block_wtIconSvg_Svg"]/*[local-name()='svg']/*[local-name()='use']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly use // to locate an SVG element. They are one of the special tags.

Always use `//*[name()='svg']` or `//*[local-name()='svg']` to locate them.

Based on the HTML that you've shared, Please use the below xpath :

```
//a[@class='svgContainer']//child::span//*[name()='svg' and starts-with(@id,'AthleteTheme')]//*[name()='use']
```

** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

**Code trial 1 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='svgContainer']//child::span//*[name()='svg' and starts-with(@id,'AthleteTheme')]//*[name()='use']").click()
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='svgContainer']//child::span//*[name()='svg' and starts-with(@id,'AthleteTheme')]//*[name()='use']"))).click()
```

**Code trial 3 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='svgContainer']//child::span//*[name()='svg' and starts-with(@id,'AthleteTheme')]//*[name()='use']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='svgContainer']//child::span//*[name()='svg' and starts-with(@id,'AthleteTheme')]//*[name()='use']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```